# How to manage nested class across multiple inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a simulation in which I have a base class called `Animal` and classes deriving from it like `Fox` and `Hare`. I need to gather a lot of information about population of the animals, including: `count`, `maleCount`, `adultCount` and many more. To keep it clean I created a static nested class:

```
public class Animal {
    protected static class Stats {
        public static int count;
        public static int maleCount;
        // and many more...
    }

    private static Stats stats = new Stats();
    public static Stats getStats() {
        return stats;
    }

    protected void foo() {    //protected method using Stats
        if (getStats.maleCount > 2)
            bar();
    }
}

public class Fox extends Animal {    //Hare created similarly
    private static Stats stats = new Stats();
    public static Stats getStats() {
        return stats;
    }
}
```

The `foo` function uses `Stats` and it should use the version from the proper inherited class (so if we call `foo()` in `Fox` it should use `Stats` from `Fox`).

The main problem now is that calling

```
Fox.getStats().count
```

from another class (eg. `Main`) results in an error:

```
Error:(61, 42) java: main.Animal.Stats.count is defined in an inaccessible class or interface
```

What is a solution to the problem? Is this approach of nested class with a getter even correct?

Comment: I've included an alternate answer to implementing *your* problem. Let me know your thoughts on it. If it deviates too much from your approach, I'd be happy to alter it or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `Stats` from a different class, it must be public.

The protected access modifier will restrict access from classes other than the ones in the same package and its subclasses.